# Busca valor correspondente ao peso

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, select

Tenho uma tabela com valores, onde cada valor é de acordo com o peso (Kg).

> Até 3kg  = R$20.00
>
> Até 5kg  = R$25.00
>
> Até 10kg = R$28.00

```
SELECT estado, kg, valorCap, valorExcedCap, valorAloremCap, prazoCap 
  FROM transportadoras_valores 
    WHERE id_transportadora = '1' && estado = 'AL' && kg = '4'
```

Nesse exemplo acima, preciso que retorne o valor referente a 5kg.

**Tenho um exemplo online:**

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/06ce6/5

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Podes fazer assim:

```
SELECT estado, kg, valorCap, valorExcedCap, valorAloremCap, prazoCap 
  FROM transportadoras_valores 
  WHERE id_transportadora = 1 && estado = 'AL' && kg >= 4
  ORDER BY kg ASC
  LIMIT 1
```

Dessa maneira dizes que queres que seja um só resultado, o primeiro a ser maior ou igual ao valor que passaste à query.

Comment: Isso, faltava o LIMIT 1

Comment: E o sinal de >=

Comment: @Tiago e o ORDER BY :P, senão no caso de o SQL não ordenar pode dar asneira se na tabela os kg não tiverem ordenados. Eu colocava por segurança.

Comment: Muito obrigado mais uma vez

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT estado, kg, valorCap, valorExcedCap, valorAloremCap, prazoCap 
FROM transportadoras_valores 
WHERE id_transportadora = '1' && estado = 'AL' && kg > '3' && kg <= '5')
```

Comment: Luiz, não pode ser assim, porque nunca é o numero exato. Uma caixa pode ter 4 quilos e 500 gramas (4.500).

Comment: Acho que ele precisa de uma condição para dar o primeiro valor maior que um certo peso para calcular o preço, e não mudar o select de 4 para 5 manualmente.

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT estado, kg, valorCap, valorExcedCap, valorAloremCap, prazoCap
    FROM transportadoras_valores 
    WHERE id_transportadora = '1' && estado = 'AL' && kg = '5'
```

Comment: Acho que ele precisa de uma condição para dar o primeiro valor maior que um certo peso para calcular o preço, e não mudar o select de 4 para 5 manualmente.

Comment: Sebastia, não pode ser assim, porque nunca é o numero exato. Uma caixa pode ter 4 quilos e 500 gramas (4.500).